# Search through JSON query from Valve API in Python

Tags: python, json

I am looking to find various statistics about players in games such as **CS:GO** from the Steam Web API, but cannot work out how to search through the JSON returned from the query (e.g. [*here*](http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=FE3C600EB76959F47F80C707467108F2&steamid=76561198185148697)) in Python.

I just need to be able to get a specific part of the list that is provided, e.g. finding `total_kills` from the link above. If I had a way that could sort through all of the information provided and filters it down to just that specific thing (in this case `total_kills`) then that would help a load!

The code I have at the moment to turn it into something Python can read is:

`url = "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=FE3C600EB76959F47F80C707467108F2&steamid=76561198185148697&include_appinfo=1"
data = requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads(data)`

Comment: Search? Search for what? Search for games? Search for players? Search for stats?

Comment: I want to search through for various statistics such as total kills and total deaths

Comment: Please do not comment, use the edit button to add additional information to your question. And be specific, right now the question is too broad, if someone tries to answer, he has to write a blog post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to search through the stats list then try this:

```
import requests
import json

def findstat(data, stat_name):
    for stat in data['playerstats']['stats']:
        if stat['name'] == stat_name:
            return stat['value']

url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=FE3C600EB76959F47F80C707467108F2&steamid=76561198185148697"
data = requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads(data)

total_kills = findstat(data, 'total_kills') # change 'total_kills' to your desired stat name
print(total_kills)
```